# How to check in .NET code to CVS in Eclipse

Tags: .net, eclipse, cvs

Just wonder anyone has such experience. I can check out .NET code from CVS in eclipse. but can't find how to compare my change with remote version, how to check in my changes to CVS in eclipse.

My source control server is CVS, I check out my C# project from it using Eclipse. Now I make changes in Visual Studio, and want to check in my changes to CVS repository.  I can't figure out how to check in my changes(C#) to CVS using Eclipse.  I do not have CVS NT (not free any more), no other CVS client installed yet. Just wonder if I can find a way to do it in Eclipse then I will not have to purchase CVS client. thanks

Comment: Going to need some more details here

Answer (score 0):

You compare your local changes against the remote by using the Synchronize view in the Team Synchronizing perspective.  You can check in your changes from there.  You can also access much of the Team functionality by right-clicking on the resource and going to the Team submenu.

See [Team CVS tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-64a_another.htm) for more info.